# Why java.util.Iterator does not reset in a nested loop?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

As I run this code, the iterator `iter` is empty the second time I use it. I am instantiating `iter` each time in the outer loop, but it does not help! That is, after the first iteration, the length of the iterable is zero!

Why is that so? And what is the general practice for this scenario that I am missing?

```
String path = "somefile.csv";
try {
        Reader in = new FileReader(path);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader(MetadataExtractorForTables.HeaderType.class)
                .withDelimiter('\t').parse(in);

        // A stupid loop
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                
            Iterator<CSVRecord> iter = records.iterator();
            System.out.println("---> " + Iterators.size(iter));
            System.out.println("--> " + StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), false).count());

            /* ----------------------------------------
             * here I would like to use the iterator
             * in a (nested) loop
             * ---------------------------------------- */
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
---> 191
--> 0
---> 0
--> 0
---> 0
--> 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an evil, contract-breaking Iterable.

From the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html):

> It is not possible to go back, once a record has been parsed from the input stream.

You'll have to explicitly copy it into a List or the like.

Comment: For what?  Copying it to a list?

Comment: To show what should be copied to a list, and where, and how that should be used, it is best to add some code to your answer. Would you please?

Comment: I did for you. Thanks for your answer anyways.